# How to resize a group of path in PaperJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, resize, paperjs

With 3 points, I am trying to achieve: rotate, move and resize after grouping them to any Path.
Path can be any regular polygon shape.

So far it is rotating and moving well smoothly. However it fails on resizing.

Here is the [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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).

Can someone guide or correct?

***Note**: the sketch was updated to move when shape is also dragged.*

Comment: I get a feeling you should be using FabricJS: http://fabricjs.com/

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Tried that before. They are not good at intersection, Non-trivial collision detection. Check the author has itself mentioned here: [link](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/wiki/When-to-use-Fabric)

Comment: Your post has nothing about collision ... and for the record collision is not trivial in paperJS

Comment: @HelderSepulveda that's correct my post is about resize issue which is a bit part of my actual requirement am trying to achieve. PaperJS has passed all the validations with the ability of doing in many ways and more advanced. Though not simple as fabricjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to use the `point` argument of the `item.scale()` method.
It allows scaling the item around a custom point and not around its center, which is the default behavior.
You also have to cancel the group dragging when the scaling operation is active, like you already do with the rotation.
Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) demonstrating a simplified solution to your problem (only handles uniform scaling) that should get you on the track.